# Query by values in array

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query a Table with a Hash and Range key for all Items whose Range match a value in an array. I'm using the `aws-sdk` npm module. When I run the below scan I get a ValidationException.

```
client.scan({
    TableName: "MyTable",
    ScanFilter: {
        HashID: {
            AttributeValueList: [ { "S": "hash" } ],
            ComparisonOperator: "EQ",
        },
        RangeID: {
            AttributeValueList: [ {"SS": ["a", "b"]} ],
            ComparisonOperator: "IN"
        },
    },
}
```

Error response:

```
{ [ValidationException: The attempted filter operation is not supported for the provided type]
message: 'The attempted filter operation is not supported for the provided type',
code: 'ValidationException',
name: 'ValidationException',
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false }
```

How do I do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html):

> IN : checks for exact matches.
>
> AttributeValueList can contain more than one AttributeValue of type
>   String, Number, or Binary **(not a set)**. The target attribute of the
>   comparison must be of the same type and exact value to match. A String
>   never matches a String set.

This means you can't use a string set (SS). You will probably need to pass the AttributeValueList a few AttributeValue objects with type S.